# How can I modify website html using my own chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, event-listener, webrequest

I want to modify website html using my chrome extension automatically. In my JS code, I have limited code as I have no idea how I can go through each line of html on a website and change values.

To clarify, I am NOT asking how to link JS to HTML or anything similar. I am asking how can I go on a website like gmail or youtube and modify the client side html code using my JS file. Lets say I have some element ID, how could I edit the value of that id? I tried going through google chrome's extension reference sheet and documentation but could not find an answer to my question, but have found ways to block urls.

Some secondary questions:

How does chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener work?
How does the "details" argument work?

I began to go about this by coding the following, as I already made a manifest.json and linked it accordingly. Sorry if this is something really simple or my code doesn't make sense, as I tried to look at other people's examples and replicate it.

JS file:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
   function(details){

     
       
       {urls: catalog.js}
   }
)
```

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Test Extension", 
    "description": "Learning how to make google extensions",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "1.0", 
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["main.js", "catalog.js"]
    },

    "permissions": ["webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "background"]
    
}
```

Comment: Use a *content script*.

Comment: Alternatively write a bookmarklet

Comment: I used a content script but now I get this error by chrome, "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null"

Comment: Add an [MCVE](/help/mcve).